# Error in defining variable

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I have a table of cells , in which one of the column is the seat number. However the seat number contains some string values such as 146A and most numericals such as 146. However in vba, when I use the seat number to vlookup, I am unable to find the right variable as if I `dim seatno as integer` then values such as 146A would give errors and if i `dim seat no as string` the numericals dont work .I formatted the whole seat no column to text in excel but the error persists. Hencei would need help on how I can define the variable which would show all values ranging from 1 to 146A.  This is the code I have done

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

   Dim answer As Integer
   answer = TextBox1.Value
   TextBox2.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(answer, Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:E"), 2, False)
   TextBox3.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(answer, Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:E"), 3, False)
   TextBox4.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(answer, Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:E"), 4, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you have half numbers and half text in `Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:B")`. Fix the data so that they are all text. By default, text is left-aligned in a cell. Numbers are right-aligned.

Comment: I left aligned them and highlighted the whole column to convert to text format but still giving errors @Jeeped

Comment: If `Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:B")` is definitively text values (including text-that-looks-like-a-number) then use `Dim answer As String`.

Comment: yup i did that but gives errors when i type in the (text that looks like a number) @Jeeped

Comment: See expanded lookup conditions below. Posting redacted sample data may be the most expedient way of arriving at a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If column B in Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet") is definitely text then declare *answer* as a string.

```
Dim answer As String
answer = TextBox1.Value
TextBox2.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(answer, _
                   Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:E"), 2, False)
```

If there are a combination of strings (e.g. `146A`) and true numbers (e.g. `146`) in 'L12 - Data Sheet'!B:B then retrieve the value from TextBox1 as a string and attempt to convert it to a true number.

```
Dim answer As String
answer = TextBox1.Value
TextBox2.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Iif(IsNumeric(answer), Int(answer), answer), _
                   Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:E"), 2, False)
```

If there is no consistent value type to the values in 'L12 - Data Sheet'!B:B then hit it with everything you've got available.

```
Dim answer As Variant, mtch As Long
answer = TextBox1.Value

Select Case True
    Case Not IsError(Application.Match(CStr(answer), Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Columns(2), 0))
        mtch = Application.Match(CStr(answer), Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Columns(2), 0)
    Case Not IsError(Application.Match(Int(answer), Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Columns(2), 0))
        mtch = Application.Match(Int(answer), Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Columns(2), 0)
End Select

'error control needed here in case mtch is still not a row number
debug.print mtch
TextBox2.Value = Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Cells(mtch, "C").Value
TextBox3.Value = Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Cells(mtch, "D").Value
TextBox4.Value = Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Cells(mtch, "E").Value
```

Comment: all codes are getting an error on answer=Textbox1.value. Probably because the programme expects it to be number but it came out as a string

Comment: See my revised Variant approach above. It would help to see some actual data. Post a link to redacted data in a sample workbook.

Comment: select manually your column, then right clic, then format cells , then in the first tab (number), go to category and select text...  And as variables you use Strings